# Can hydrogen peroxide and propane be a good rocket propellant combination?

Tags: engines, fuel, hydrogen-peroxide

The decomposition of hydrogen peroxide can be used to spin the turbopump and then  it can be mixed with propane in the combustion chamber

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer - good for what? Hydrogen peroxide offers worse performance than LO2, and can explode all by itself. Propane combines disadvantages of cryofuels and complex hydrocarbons. The combination is a bit too dangerous for amateurs, and too weak for professional use, but I guess 3rd world countries might find it attractive for military uses.

Answer (score 3):

This combination is certainly workable. The question is if there would not be much better alternatives for most use cases.

### Propane

At a glance, propane looks rather good as fuel on paper. It is in between methane and RP-1 in both density (500-510 kg/m3 at 10°C), and energy density (50 Mj/kg). It is also easier to store than methane, but a bit harder than RP-1, as it needs moderate cooling and/or pressurization, but safe enough that it is sold to the general public at gas stations. As with methane, autogenous pressurization should be possible, but the weight of the remaining gas would be a bit high; this is not an option with RP-1. For some reason it is still rarely used as a rocket propellant.

### Hydrogen Peroxide

High test peroxide (HTP) has some favorable properties. Its density is high at around 1450 kg/m^3, it is storable at reasonable temperatures and not as toxic as common storable oxidizers.
However, it gives significantly less combustion temperature than liquid oxygen or combinations of di-nitrogen tetra-oxide and nitric acid, and although the high water content in the exhaust helps with more efficient expansion it is not enough to make up for this, it has lower specific impulse. However, if there is a need to limit the combustion temperature, as was the case for some early rocket engines, this may actually be beneficial.

HTP was still used for space launches in the black arrow program, and Skyrora plans to use HTP in the way proposed in the question, in a closed cycle staged combustion. Both of the above cases use kerosene fuel.
While the energetic decomposition of HTP gives interesting options for gas generation or for use as a monopropellant, it is also a considerable hazard. For rocket propulsion this may be considered acceptable and manageable.

### The combination

The relatively low density of propane would not matter much, as HTP would take up about 2.5x more volume anyway. Both propane and HTP should probably be kept cool, something like 0-10 °C, to lower the vapor pressure for propane and spontaneous decomposition for HTP.
Neither propane nor HTP are very popular to begin with, and they hardly complement each other in a way to make the combination competitive with more established combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen peroxide is heavier than water, and same is for propane.  This leads to a lower specific impulse than hydrolox.  Other reasons about disadvantages are the cost and efficiency.  Propane is more expensive than methane, used in methanolox for Starship.  As in the comment above, the hydrogen perioxide can explode by itself, destroying the rocket and all the work and money put into it.

Comment: However, denser propellants lead to more compact fuel tankage, which has benefits that can offset the mass-specific impulse penalty.

Comment: For Example: Black Arrow

Comment: Liquid propane is less dense than water. Also it is misleading to say higher density leads to lower specific impulse. It is true in terms of volumetric energy density, but that approach is not standard.